# Not able to get drawable file name

Tags: android, drawable

I am trying to save image to SD card so I have written a method 
`BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.);` this method I need a name of drawable file but I am not able to get my drawable file name.

Please let me know whats the mistake I have made here.

attached link of the same.(as screenshot attachmet is not allowed by stackoverflow)
[click here to check the problem mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqHAg.jpg)

Comment: try to clean project and then build project

Comment: Place file in mipmap and try to get that.

Comment: you should clean and rebuild your project then it will work fine :)

Comment: Where is the drawable saved? Is it packaged with your APK or is it a separate image file?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice separate image file

Comment: Where does the file come from?

Answer (score 2):

As suggestions given by @chandani c patel,@ Umair we need to clean and rebuild the project then we will be able to get the drwable file in  `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.f);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, first try to **clean project** and **build project**. And even if still doesn't show your **resource** in suggestions, just type manually,

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.f);`

It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to access a file which is in the `res/drawable` folder on your development computer. This file is compiled into the APK which you install on an Android device as an app. To access the file, use `R.drawable.f`.

You seem to expect that Android Studio will provide this name in its autocomplete list. Under ideal circumstances, this is true. However, `R` is generated by the Android build tools and easily becomes out of sync with the files and other resources in your project. As several comments have mentioned, you can clean and rebuild your project. Alternatively, you can click on the "Sync with Gradle" button in the toolbar. Either of these actions should rebuild the `R.java` file so that it accurately represents the files in the `res` subdirectory of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 solutions:

1. Clean and rebuild project
2. File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...